# Выполнение jquery кода на конкретном устройстве

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте! подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне написать такое условие на jquery, что бы оно выполнялось только на устройствах с маленьким разрешением экрана, а на десктопе не выполнялось. css и медиа запросы не подходят, нужно именно на jquery.
заранее спасибо.

Comment: А почему именно `jQuery`? Вид лучше рендерить через стили.

Comment: Потому что обработка неких действий и результат их работы выводятся с помощью jquery и прикрутить туда css не получается. Поэтому и думаю, как это сделать с jquery, наверняка ведь есть какой то способ.

Comment: Мне лень переводить этот ответ, но он может вам пригодиться:http://stackoverflow.com/a/8876069/2902432

Answer (score 2):

[используйте window.matchMedia.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)
Подпишитесь на изменения размеров окна и в зависимости от совпадений выполняйте условия

```
if (window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 768px)").matches) {
    div.addClass("some-class");
} else {
 // ширина экрана меньше 768 пикселей
}
```

Comment: Не используйте ссылки в качестве ответа. Как полезная нагрузка - может быть, но не как цельный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо всем, помогли разобраться !